# Run job only once when created merge request CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE

Tags: gitlab-ci

```
job1:
  extends: .parentJob
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /.*JOB1.*/' 
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /.*JOB1.*/'
```

My purpose is to run job1 in 3 scenarious:

1. directly from branch pushing commit with tag containing JOB1
2. when creating MR with title containing JOB1
3. using scheduled pipeplines (I set up CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE equal to JOB1 and thats how job is running)

Unfortunately whenever I merge my MR job1 is start running and duplicate my pipeline. How to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Does this mean that you want to have the pipeline run only when there is a MR?
If that is the case you can use the only keyword for when you have a MR.
Otherwise the except for when you want to exclude your main branch where you merge to for example:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#onlyrefs--exceptrefs-examples

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).